# Error-Class User contains 1 abstract method

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried everything as you can see in these two forum links. No one is able to give a solution.

I added the remember_token field in db with varchar 255 and null

My table is correctly named users

I added the three required functions to my User model in order for Auth to work.

All my code looks correct as others have said.

[laravel forum](http://laravel.io/forum/07-09-2014-error-class-user-contains-1-abstract-method)
[php academy forum](https://phpacademy.org/topics/error-class-user-contains-1-abstract-method/37144?page=1#last)

Here is the error:

```
Class User contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface::getAuthIdentifier)
```

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;


class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

protected $fillable = array('email', 'username', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'active');
/**
* The DB table used by the model
*
*@var string
*/
protected $table = 'users';

/**
* The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form
*
*@var array
*/
protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
* Get the unique identifier for the user
*
* @return mixed
*/
public function getAuthIndentifier() 
{
    return $this->getkey();
}

/**
* Get the password for the user.
*
* @return string
*/
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
* Get the email address where password reminders are sent.
*
* @return string
*/
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getRememberToken()
{   
return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
$this->remember_token = $value;
}   

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
return 'remember_token';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of an abstract method is spelt wrong:

`getAuthIndentifier()`  should be `getAuthIdentifier()`

```
 /**
  * Get the unique identifier for the user
  *
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function getAuthIndentifier() //<----bad spelling!!!!
  {
        return $this->getkey();
   }
```

...I'm assuming you really didn't intend to create a method `getAuthIndentifier()`

Comment: Thank you, a simple mistake. That got rid of the error, however, the auth is still not being recognized because in my conditional my error 'Email/password wrong, or account not activated yet?' is showing. I even changed the conditional to true or false, and false come up every time. My auth is not being recognized.

Comment: That is a separate problem from the question you've posed here. You should accept the answer and create another question with the relevant code.

Comment: I already did and no answers yet [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664191/auth-in-laravel-not-being-recognized)

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit `getAuthIdentified()`, instead you have declared a method with a typo

```
/**
* Get the unique identifier for the user
*
* @return mixed
*/
public function getAuthIndentifier() 
{
    return $this->getkey();
}
```

`iNdentifier`. Your IDE should tell you if you have overriden a method, and if not, you'd probably know it's not an override, but a whole new method. In Eclipse, NetBeans and PHPStorm, a colored circle similar to a breakpoint is on that line.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the error, however my auth is still not working. Please see @Ray post